# Getting error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'SERVER_IP' (99)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP5 and MySQL, everything is fine until more than 9,000 petitions are send to MySQL server.

For example, I'm trying to do 10,000 insert from a CSV file with 10,000 records (lines).
When the loop is running I got this error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.10.11' (99).

I wrote a little loop to do 10,000 `select field_id from table where field_id = XX` and I got the same error.

My LAMP uses Debian Squeeze, PHP5, MySQL Server 5.1, Apache2

An important note: Using MySQL Workbench or MySQL CLI there are no errors, is only on web environment.

This is my.conf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
language    = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve

wait_timeout=60
connect_timeout=10
max_allowed_packet=16M
interactive_timeout=120
join_buffer_size=1M
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_limit=2M
table_cache=1024
sort_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
key_buffer = 256M
key_buffer_size=64M

#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
#key_buffer     = 16M
#max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
#query_cache_limit  = 1M
#query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into timeout issues and too many connections. Try lowering your wait_timeout and maybe the interactive_timeout.

I don't know if you're using PDO (recommended from all the posts I've seen here), but try making the MySQL connection a persistent one so that it doesn't have to keep opening new connections for each update.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the persistent connection works!

Now I'm reading about PDO, it seems to be the best option!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in several MariaDB installations:

Step 1 - Edit sysctl:

`sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf`

Step 2 - Paste these lines:

`net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
 net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
 net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30
 net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=8192`

Basically this will keep connections opened for longer period

Step 3: Apply the settings

`sudo sysctl -p`

This should fix the issue.

Comment: This helped me a lot when using OTRS storage switching tool (for version 3.1.7) bin/otrs.ArticleStorageSwitch.pl -s ArticleStorageDB -d ArticleStorageFS since it was just growing the connections count and dying at 28k ;) With your settings it was going max up to 400. Cheers